# Record child processes in Linux

Tags: linux, child-process, pstree

I'm looking for a way to record child processes and their arguments spawned by a script or other command.  A good example would be recording the build commands spawned by "make" and any children they, in turn, spawn.

In my specific case working with a build script from an embedded systems manufacturer.  It's a Python script that calls cmake, ninja, and heaven knows what else.  I'd really like to know what's being called so I can maybe pare down the noise.

This seems like an obvious utility for someone to have written decades ago but I'll be darned if I can find it.

Much thanks for any advice.

Comment: There's always [strace](https://strace.io/), which lets you record system calls. If you collect all the `execve` calls you'll have a good idea what's going on.

Comment: Will strace follow child proceses?

Comment: Yes. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: Looks like that got what I needed.  Thank you.